# wp_nav_menu sort order?

Tags: theme-development, menus

Hey Guys,
I'm trying to build a right aligned, wrapping capable wp_nav_menu powered menu.

Is there a way to have it rendered backwards, so that float: right; would work and not mess up the order?

I was hoping for something like this:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array('sort_order' => 'DESC' )); ?>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just found this handy little function that ads the ability to reverse the menu output order. it might come in handy:

```
/**
* Enables a 'reverse' option for wp_nav_menu to reverse the order of menu
* items. Usage:
*
* wp_nav_menu(array('reverse' => TRUE, ...));
*/
function my_reverse_nav_menu($menu, $args) {
if (isset($args->reverse) && $args->reverse) {
return array_reverse($menu);
}
return $menu;
}
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_objects', 'my_reverse_nav_menu', 10, 2);
```

All you need to do is ad `'reverse' => true` as one of the wp_nav_menu parameters. :)

this is the source: https://gist.github.com/1291914

Answer (score 0):

You could write a custom walker for your `wp_nav_menu()` call. Short of that, I don't think there's anyway to do what you're trying to do.

You could pass such arguments to your fallback function (e.g. `wp_list_pages()` or `wp_page_menu()`), but the list-item order of `wp_nav_menu()` is entirely dependent upon the user-defined menu applied to the given menu location.

Comment: Thanks Chip! It's not often you "can't" do something in WordPress.

Funny you answered this question, I just emailed you through your website about a plugin question! What a coincidence!

Answer (score 0):

oops! or try like this

```
<?php $args = array( 'sort_column' => 'menu_order, post_title' ); ?>
```

for more parameters http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_page_menu

Comment: this might help you [http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu)

Comment: Please edit your answer to add details instead of creating multiple answers.